# Generic type not replaced in groovy stubs

Tags: generics, groovy, gradle, stub

I have a generic trait for getting single version of an entity via Hibernate Envers:

```
trait EntitySingleVersionRepository<ENTITY, ID> {

 @Inject
 private AuditReader auditReader

 public ENTITY getEntityChangedAt(int revision, ID entityId) {
    ENTITY ret = getEntityAtRevsion(revision, entityId)
    initializeHibernateCollections(ret)
    return ret;
 }

 private ENTITY getEntityAtRevsion(int revision, ID entityId) {
     final ENTITY ret = (ENTITY) auditReader.createQuery()
            .forEntitiesAtRevision(Parafia.class, revision)
            .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(entityId))
            .getSingleResult();
    ret
 }

 abstract void initializeHibernateCollections(ENTITY entity)
}
```

I have a similar `EntityVersionListRepository` trait for getting a list of revisions at which the entity was modified. I implement the traits on a single repository:

```
class MyEntityVersionRepository implements EntityVersionListRepository<MyEntity, Long>,
    EntitySingleVersionRepository<MyEntity, Long>,
    Serializable {

@Override
void initializeHibernateCollections(MyEntity entity) {
    MyEntityUtil.initializeHibernateCollections(entity)
}
```

}

When I try to compile the code I get an error in the groovy stubs about unresolved ID and ENTITY symbols as if the generic types have not been replaced by the actual type, e.g.

```
/home/kamil/java/archidiecezja/build/tmp/compileGroovy/groovy-java-stubs/pl/aw/business/myentity/boundary/MyEntityVersionRepository.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
public  ENTITY getEntityChangedAt(int revision, ID entityId) { return null;}
                                                ^
  symbol:   class ID
  location: class MyEntityVersionRepository
```

I use gradle 2.6 groovy bundled plugin for compilation

Comment: I have faced the same issue, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: It seems the error (MyEntityChangeHistoryRepository) doesn't match your class name (MyEntityVersionRepository).

Comment: Wrong copy and paste, now it is correct